# Arduino + Python

Tags: python, arduino

Возникла проблема: при отправке команды на ардуино serial-порт каждый раз открывается заново, что приводит к перезагрузке платы.

Придумал такое решение: поставить зацикленную программу с постоянно открытым serial-портом, которая каждый цикл читает файл. А в этот файл уже писать команды с веб-сервера.

Вопрос: возможна ли такая ситуация, что команда в файл неполностью записалась одной программой, а другая программа (зацикленная, которая отправляет команды через порт) прочла эти неполные данные? И что с этим делать?

Comment: возможно надо просто поставить флаг в самом файле, в конце, который говорит о том, что данные верны, если флага нет, то читать еще раз.

Comment: Сброс ардуины при подключении по USB - это аппаратная особенность всех плат. Решения два: оставлять порт открытым, либо дорабатывать аппаратно ардуину(кроме некоторых моделей). Если нужна аппаратная доработка - могу написать в ответе как ее делать.

Answer (score 0):

Серийный порт хранит всю информацию до момента её прочтения помещая её в так званый буфер. Буфер хранит информацию до момента его прочтения или сброса (очисткой его или перезагрузкой программы).

> возможна ли такая ситуация, что команда в файл неполностью записалась
> одной программой, а другая программа (зацикленная, которая отправляет
> команды через порт) прочла эти неполные данные? И что с этим делать?

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос:**

- Порт может слушать только одна программа, у вас не получиться подключиться к одному порту двумя программами, порт блокируется.
- Если вы отправили команду и программа не успела её прочитать - то вы эту команду теряете.
- Да, вы можете записывать эти команды в файл и дальше с ними работать.